# Java Spam Filter

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a spam filter in Java using the Bayesian algorithm.

I use a text file that contains email messages and split the tokens using regex, storing these values into a hashmap.

My problem is, with regex, the email addresses are split so instead of:
johnsmith@example.com

regex causes the token to be:
john
smith
example

The same holds true for ip addresses, so for example, instead of:
192.55.34.322

regex splits the tokens to be:
192
55
34
322

So does anybody know of a way that I could read the email messages and store their contents as is?

AMENDMENT: I am using a regex that does not keep ip addresses or email addresses. It splits these up.

I was wondering if regex was not the way to go and if I could be suggested any alternatives for me to be able to filter emails to pick out characteristics I desire.

Comment: Is your question about creating a regex that does not split on dots? Or is the regex fixed and you need a way to get the original email and ip address back?

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to separate the body of the email from the header information before you tokenize.

Comment: how would this be possible when some header information differs for the test emails I have?